# How to define a non lambda args_converter function?

Tags: kivy

In the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html?highlight=listview#using-an-args-converter) it's shown that an args_converter can be written as a regular function or as a lambda function, but i can't seem to get it to work with a non lambda one, and all examples i see are lambdas.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
def groupArgsConv(index, item):
    res = {'text': item['title'],
               'size_hint_y': None,
               'heigth': '25dp'}
    return res

self.ids.grouplist.adapter = ListAdapter(args_converter=groupArgsConv,
                                             data=self.groups,
                                             cls=ListItemLabel)
```

This doesn't work, but this does:

```
list_item_args_converter = lambda index, item: {'text': item['title'],
                                             'size_hint_y': None,
                                             'height': '25dp'}

self.ids.grouplist.adapter = ListAdapter(args_converter=list_item_args_converter,
                                             data=self.groups,
                                             cls=ListItemLabel)
```

Why? How do i get the 1st example to work?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemLabel, ListView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

data = [{'title': str(i)} for i in range(100)]

def groupArgsConv(index, item):
    res = {'text': item['title'],
           'size_hint_y': None,
           'height': '25dp'}
    return res

list_adapter = ListAdapter(
    data=data,
    args_converter=groupArgsConv,
    cls=ListItemLabel)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(ListView(adapter=list_adapter))
```

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you have some kind of an exception or strange output in the log?